# How to convert grayscale image to binary image and reverse the process in python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a task to convert a grayscale image to binary and then take it back to its original form. I am using threshold function from opencv to convert the gray image into a binary. Is there any way to reconvert the binary image to the gray one?

Comment: Are you trying to convert a binary image with only black and white into a grayscale image?

Comment: no, there is no way of converting a binary image into a gray scale one. The information is lost when you take the (typically) eight bit per pixel of the grey scale image and map it into the one bit pixel of the binary image. There is no way of guessing what was there (unless you are using deep learning for hallucinating the information)

Comment: is there no way to do one-to-one mapping of pixels so that it can be regained?

Comment: Why don't you keep two copies of the grayscale image. Use one copy to do the thresholding and then use submat to replace the thresholding with grayscale using the other copy

Comment: This will be  the last option left  .. but can't we use Histogram Equilisation or Image intensity transformation domain or any other method  ?

Comment: No, there is no way. You can't map the binary values `0` and `1` to 256 (or more) grayscale values.

Answer (score 4):

You can follow the below steps to convert gray scale image to binary image :

i- read a grayscale image by importing cv2

```
import cv2
im_gray = cv2.imread('path_of_grayscale_image.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
```

ii-  convert grayscale image to binary

```
(thresh, im_bw) = cv2.threshold(im_gray, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
```

which determines the threshold automatically from the image using Otsu's method, or if you already know the threshold you can use:

```
thresh = 127
im_bw = cv2.threshold(im_gray, thresh, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]
```

iii- save

```
cv2.imwrite('binary_image.png', im_bw)
```

Comment: I need a code which can also do vice versa of this i.e create binary image to   grayscale image